# Python 3 - Using recursion in a linked list

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, linked-list

Python 3 - I am new to coding and am finding recursion difficult. I'm making a linked list class with recursive methods for adding and removing items from the list. Right now, I am unable to remove an item if it happens to be the first item in my list. I wrote some alternative code which could remove the first item from the list if I included another parameter (previous) and another base case, but then I could *only* remove the first item and spent way too long trying to figure out why so I scrapped that entirely. I would appreciate a hint!

Also, I am already aware that I have getters and am not using them properly.

```
class Node:
    """
    Represents a node in a linked list
    """
    def __init__(self, data):
        self._data = data
        self._next = None

    def get_data(self):
        """getter method for data in Node class"""
        return self._data

    def get_next(self):
        """getter method for next in Node class"""
        return self._next
class LinkedList:
    """
    A linked list implementation of the List ADT
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self._head = None

    def get_head(self):
        """getter function for head of list"""
        return self._head

    def add(self, val):
        """ Adds a node containing val to the linked list - helper function"""
        self._head = self.recursive_add(self._head, val)

    def recursive_add(self, node1, val):
        """ Adds a node containing val to the linked list """
        if node1 is None:
            return Node(val)
        else:
            node1._next = self.recursive_add(node1._next, val)
            return node1

    def remove(self, val):
        """removed the node containing val from the linked list - helper function"""
        self.recursive_remove(self._head, val)

    def recursive_remove(self, node1, val):
        """
        Removes the node containing val from the linked list
        """
        if node1 is None:
            return node1
        elif node1._data == val:
            return node1._next
        else:
            node1._next = self.recursive_remove(node1._next, val)
            return node1

    def main():
       my_list = LinkedList()
       my_list.add(13)
       my_list.add(9)
       my_list.add(5)
       my_list.remove(9)
    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: If you use recursion, your code won't be able to handle lists longer than 1000 elements in CPython. Better to use loops, although I presume this is purely for pedagogical purposes. Can you not make an assignment to the head in `self.recursive_remove(self._head, val)`?

Comment: Haha now I guess there is a course using the same linked list class: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69908090/recursively-insert-node-in-linked-list-given-position-and-value

Comment: To remove a given node, simply say that `node.next = node.next.next`. Or if you are trying to remove the first node, you can just say `node = node.next`

Answer (score 1):

```
    def remove(self, val):
        """removed the node containing val from the linked list - helper function"""
        if self._head and self._head._data == val:
            self._head = self._head._next
            return
        self.recursive_remove(self._head, val)
```

if its at the start, the head needs to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

In `remove` you call `recursive_remove`, but ignore its return value. You should use it as the (potentially different) `_head` reference, must like is done in the recursive method itself, where you have:

```
node1._next = self.recursive_remove(node1._next, val)
#       ^                                   │
#       └───────────────────────────────────┘
```

Note how `node1._next` is passed as argument, and the method's return value is the (potentially different) reference that `node1._next` should end up with. The *same* pattern should be applied in the initial call in `remove`:

```
def remove(self, val):
    self._head = self.recursive_remove(self._head, val)
#          ^                                  │
#          └──────────────────────────────────┘
```

NB: the same pattern is used in `add`, where you do it correctly.